# mod_rewrite should serve files that exist in document root but is ignoring them

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I've lifted most of this from Wordpress, so any path on the domain like say `/search` or `/list` is directed to `/index.php`. Fine that works.

However, it should not do that if the file being requested *exists in the document root*. So if I request `/exists.php` it should run that script. Instead it's *ignoring* files on the filesystem and continues to serve `index.php`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  DocumentRoot /home/sites/dev
  ServerName dev.vbox

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule . /index.php

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/dev.error.log

</VirtualHost>
```

I've gone through the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and various Google search results but I don't see anything wrong with my rewrite conditions. If the requested filename is a file or a directory, do not redirect to `/index.php`.

I've `cd` to the doc root and listed the contents of that directory, the file I'm requesting exists. My apache access log has entries for `/exists.php`.

The document root is a mounted directory that lives on the my Mac and the VM serving the request is Ubuntu install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding another rewrite condition, so my working Virtualhost looked like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html
  ServerName domain.com

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^.*\.(php)$ [nocase]
  RewriteRule . /index.php

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `%{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME}` instead of `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`.  The LA-U prefix is needed before the request is mapped to the filesystem.

**Edit:**

Didn't catch it in my first pass, you also need to change the first argument to RewriteRule like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/sites/dev
    ServerName dev.vbox

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* /index.php

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/dev.error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I changed both my rewrite conditions to `%{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME}`, it basically acts as if `mod_rewrite` is off, serving `exists.php` but not mapping `/search` to `index.php`. Going to `/` serves `/index.php` as you'd expect.

Comment: Add this sorted it so `exists.php` is served when requested but `/search` is still serviced by `index.php`: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^.*\.(css|js|php|html)$ [nocase]`

Comment: Didn't catch it in the first pass, added an edit about the `RewriteRule`.

Comment: I just tested this and `/search` does not work, it's doesn't redirect to `index.php` - I can access `/exists.php` though.